# Syntax for if-else branch based on user input in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

When a user is prompted with a yes or no question, each user might respond differently. Say for example, responses for yes could be yeah, why not, sure, im okay with it, yup etc and similarly to respond for no users could say nope, nah, no.

I want to send a response if the user input belongs to Yes class and send a different response if he has uttered words from No type in Bot Framework Composer.

Under Expected Responses I created entities with value to distinguish the two classes as below

```
  -{Accept = yeah}
  -{Accept = Yea}
  -{Accept = yup}
  -{Accept = that will work}
  -{Accept = why not}
  -{Accept = yep}
  -{Accept = yes}
  -{Accept = yeah sure}
  -{Reject = No}
  -{Reject = Nope}
  -{Reject = nah}
```

screenshot of the composer window

[image]

How to write condition checking the user input with the defined class?

Comment: why you are not using choice input ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-control-conversation-flow?tabs=v2x#branch-ifelse